# Laravel 4 - Unit tests that use database access in workbench

Tags: php, laravel-4, phpunit, eloquent

I am developing a package in the workbench environment.

When i run `phpunit` i have an Eloquent exception

```
Call to a member function connection() on a non-object in [...] Eloquent/Model.php on line 2881
```

I guess that's because `app/config/testing/database.php` has not been loaded.

I just want to run my workbench package tests within the default laravel testing environment, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution i found so far

https://github.com/orchestral/testbench